# So I have been making a connect 4 game with python and the checkwinner component isn't working as intended

Tags: python

Here is the code:
The checkwinner thing isn't checking for 4 in a row, and only detects 3 then declares a winner.
some help would be appreciated.

```
grid = [["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
        [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
        [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
        [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
        [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
        [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
        [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "]]

col = 7
gameloop=True


def PrintGrid():

print(" ")
print( " | ", grid[0][0]," | ", grid[0][1]," | ", grid[0][2]," | ", grid[0][3]," | ", grid[0]           [4]," | ", grid[0][5]," | ", grid[0][6]," | ")
print(" -------------------------------------------")
print( " | ", grid[1][0]," | ", grid[1][1]," | ", grid[1][2]," | ", grid[1][3]," | ", grid[1][4]," | ", grid[1][5]," | ", grid[1][6]," | ")
print(" -------------------------------------------")
print( " | ", grid[2][0]," | ", grid[2][1]," | ", grid[2][2]," | ", grid[2][3]," | ", grid[2][4]," | ", grid[2][5]," | ", grid[2][6]," | ")
print(" -------------------------------------------")
print( " | ", grid[3][0]," | ", grid[3][1]," | ", grid[3][2]," | ", grid[3][3]," | ", grid[3][4]," | ", grid[3][5]," | ", grid[3][6]," | ")
print(" -------------------------------------------")
print( " | ", grid[4][0]," | ", grid[4][1]," | ", grid[4][2]," | ", grid[4][3]," | ", grid[4][4]," | ", grid[4][5]," | ", grid[4][6]," | ")
print(" -------------------------------------------")
print( " | ", grid[5][0]," | ", grid[5][1]," | ", grid[5][2]," | ", grid[5][3]," | ", grid[5][4]," | ", grid[5][5]," | ", grid[5][6]," | ")
print(" -------------------------------------------")
print( " | ", grid[6][0]," | ", grid[6][1]," | ", grid[6][2]," | ", grid[6][3]," | ", grid[6][4]," | ", grid[6][5]," | ", grid[6][6]," | ")


    


def checkwinner1():

# Horizontal Checking:

if (grid[6][0] and grid[6][1] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif(grid[6][0] and grid[6][1] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][1] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][1] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][2] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][2] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][3] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][5] and grid[6][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][3] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][5] and grid[6][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][0] and grid[5][1] and grid[5][2] and grid[5][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][0] and grid[5][1] and grid[5][2] and grid[5][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][1] and grid[5][2] and grid[5][3] and grid[5][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][1] and grid[5][2] and grid[5][3] and grid[5][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[5][2] and grid[5][3] and grid[5][4] and grid[5][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][2] and grid[5][3] and grid[5][4] and grid[5][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[5][4] and grid[5][5] and grid[5][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[5][4] and grid[5][5] and grid[5][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
   
elif (grid[4][0] and grid[4][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[4][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][0] and grid[4][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[4][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[4][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[4][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[4][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[4][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[4][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif grid([4][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[4][5] and grid[4][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[4][5] and grid[4][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][0] and grid[3][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[3][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif grid([3][0] and grid[3][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[3][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[3][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[3][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[3][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[3][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[3][5] and grid[3][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[3][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[3][5] and grid[3][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[2][0] and grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] and grid[2][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[2][0] and grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] and grid[2][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] and grid[2][3] and grid[2][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] and grid[2][3] and grid[2][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[2][2] and grid[2][3] and grid[2][4] and grid[2][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[2][2] and grid[2][3] and grid[2][4] and grid[2][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[2][3] and grid[2][4] and grid[2][5] and grid[2][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[2][3] and grid[2][4] and grid[2][5] and grid[2][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] and grid[1][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] and grid[1][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] and grid[1][3] and grid[1][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] and grid[1][3] and grid[1][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][2] and grid[1][3] and grid[1][4] and grid[1][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][2] and grid[1][3] and grid[1][4] and grid[1][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][3] and grid[1][4] and grid[1][5] and grid[1][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[1][3] and grid[1][4] and grid[1][5] and grid[1][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

def checkwinner2():

# Vertical Checking:

if (grid[6][0] and grid[5][0] and grid[4][0] and grid[3][0]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()


elif (grid[6][0] and grid[5][0] and grid[4][0] and grid[3][0]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[5][0] and grid[4][0] and grid[3][0] and grid[2][0]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][0] and grid[4][0] and grid[3][0] and grid[2][0]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][0] and grid[3][0] and grid[2][0] and grid[1][0]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][0] and grid[3][0] and grid[2][0] and grid[1][0]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][1] and grid[5][1] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][1] and grid[5][1] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][1] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][1] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][1] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][1] and grid[1][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][1] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][1] and grid[1][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][2] and grid[5][2] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][2] and grid[5][2] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][2] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    
elif (grid[5][2] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][2] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][2] and grid[1][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[4][2] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][2] and grid[1][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][3] and grid[5][3] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][3] and grid[5][3] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][3] and grid[1][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][3] and grid[1][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][4] and grid[5][4] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][4] and grid[5][4] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][4] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][4] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][4] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][4] and grid[1][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][4] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][4] and grid[1][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][5] and grid[5][5] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][5] and grid[5][5] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][5] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][5] and grid[2][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][5] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][5] and grid[2][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][4] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][4] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][6] and grid[6][5] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][6] and grid[6][5] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][5] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][5] and grid[6][4] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][4] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][4] and grid[6][3] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

def checkwinner3():
# Diagonal Checking:

if (grid[6][0] and grid[5][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][0] and grid[5][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][1] and grid[5][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][1] and grid[5][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][2] and grid[5][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][2] and grid[5][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][3] and grid[5][4] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][3] and grid[5][4] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][6] and grid[5][5] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][6] and grid[5][5] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][5] and grid[5][4] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][5] and grid[5][4] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][4] and grid[5][3] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[6][4] and grid[5][3] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][3] and grid[5][2] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][0]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[6][3] and grid[5][2] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][0]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][0] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][0] and grid[4][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][1] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][2] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][5] and grid[2][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
    
elif (grid[5][3] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][5] and grid[2][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][6] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][6] and grid[4][5] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][5] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][5] and grid[4][4] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][4] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][4] and grid[4][3] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][0]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[5][3] and grid[4][2] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][0]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][0] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][2] and grid[1][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][0] and grid[3][1] and grid[2][2] and grid[1][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][3] and grid[1][4]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][1] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][3] and grid[1][4]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][4] and grid[1][5]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][2] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][4] and grid[1][5]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][5] and grid[1][6]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][5] and grid[1][6]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][6] and grid[3][5] and grid[2][4] and grid[1][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][6] and grid[3][5] and grid[2][4] and grid[1][3]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][5] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][3] and grid[1][2]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][5] and grid[3][4] and grid[2][3] and grid[1][2]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][4] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][2] and grid[1][1]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][4] and grid[3][3] and grid[2][2] and grid[1][1]) == "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][1] and grid[1][0]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()

elif (grid[4][3] and grid[3][2] and grid[2][1] and grid[1][0])== "y":
    print(" ")
    print("Yellow is the Winner!")
    exit()
```

`

I expect the check winner code to check for 4 of "r" or "y" in a row, then declare a winner depending on which colour wins. I also would like the code to not be changed too much.

Comment: This is an insane amount of code duplication, pretty much begging for mistakes that are hard to identify. You need to do your testing with a loop. The loop should test horizontal, vertical, and both diagonals. All you need to do is check for 4 of the same color in a row.

Comment: That said, every single one of your tests is wrong. `if (grid[6][0] and grid[6][1] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][3]) == "r"` does not do what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the check_winner() function you have written

```
if (grid[6][0] and grid[6][1] and grid[6][2] and grid[6][3]) == "r":
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
```

which is not checking if each of the grid positions are "r". Instead you want to check each one individually like:

```
if (grid[6][0] == "r") and (grid[6][1] == "r") and (grid[6][2] == "r") and (grid[6][3] == "r"):
    print(" ")
    print("Red is the Winner!")
    exit()
```

In saying this, there is significant duplication of code here that can be simplified with a for loop. For example to find horizontal lines you could do the following as a start:

```
for row in grid: #for each row
    #converts the array into a string e.g. ["r", " ", "y", "y", "y", "y", " "] -> "r yyyy "
    row_str = ''.join(row) 
    if "rrrr" in row_str:
        print(" ")
        print("Red is the Winner!")
        exit()
    if "yyyy" in row_str:
        print(" ")
        print("Yellow is the Winner!")
        exit()
```